# sudo apt update error about cdrom

Tags: gnome, updates, sudo

```
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 22.04 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20220419) jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: You have multiple issues; your missing installation media is *enabled* but can't be found, plus you've added 3rd party *personal package archive* (PPAs) that don't provide support for *jammy* or 22.04... Being 3rd party sources, checking they support your OS/release is on you to do.  These need to be removed/disabled.

Comment: а как теперь пофиксить

Comment: Just comment out the cdrom lines in /etc/apt/sources.list